# how to retrieve a selected data from sqlite and display in textview?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am facing a problem in displaying a data from SQLite database to a textview. The column of the data that I want is in column 13 and the table only have 1 row of data.

I have try for few hours but still cannot retrieve the data into the textview.

**Problem:** The textview is not showing the data from the table in SQLite database.

In my **DatabaseHelper**, I have created a cursor to get the data:

```
public Cursor getNameData() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

**Activity file**:

```
public class showName extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView name;
DatabaseHelper userDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showcvv);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    name = findViewById(R.id.userName);

    Cursor cursor = userDb.getNameData();
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(showName.this, "No data generate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String username = cursor.getString(12);
            name.setText(username);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Is there any error for the code? Any suggestion to improve this code?

Comment: If you want to read data from a database then you have to use `this.getReadableDatabase();` above you are using getWritableDatabase().

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya I still cannot get the data in textview.

Comment: but please post your error.

Comment: Move this line: `DatabaseHelper userDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);` inside onCreate().

Comment: @forpas I think you are right, because there is nothing other wrong.

Comment: @forpas I have changed the line inside onCreate(), but it still showing nothing to the textview...

Comment: Then debug to check if your code enters the do loop and if it does what is the value of username.